# Combine data-toogle with data-role in twitter bootstrap 3

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, popover, jquery-tags-input

I'm using bootstrap 3.0.0 and I'm tring to use tagsinput plugin (http://timschlechter.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/bootstrap3/) combine with popover for a text input, but the popover doesn't works. Any idea to how is it possible to combine the two plugin?

if i remove the tagsinput, the popover works fine.

```
<input  type="text" placeholder="my text" 
                                data-role="tagsinput" 
                                class="form-control input-lg" 
                                name="what" 
                                id='idInputWhat'
                                data-toggle="popover"
                                data-animation="true"
                                data-placement="bottom"
                                data-trigger="onfocus"
                                data-content="my text"
                                value="wine, sea"/>
```

Comment: have you tried initalizing popover manually? Demos of tagsinput appears to strip all attributes from input

Comment: yes, i'm already try it with $('#idInputWhat').popover(); , but doesn't works

Comment: would move popever to a parent wrapper and see if that works...create a demo in jsfiddle.net